# mysql copy data from another column

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 columns, ip_start, ip_start_long

```
ip_start        |  ip_start_long
------------------------------------
0.255.255.255   |  16777215
```

I need to convert **ip_start** `(INET_ATON)` and copy update to **ip_start_long** for all rows (1 million rows)

How can I do it in `php` or `phpmyadmin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well simple query will do this for you

```
update table set ip_start_long = INET_ATON(ip_start);
```

Comment: what if ip is ipv6? ip_start can have ipv4 & 6

Comment: you can see [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34037) that native support for ipv6 is not added. there is a link there that will take you to some `udf` functions